# Best way to save pandas DataFrame to parquet with date type

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-athena, pyarrow

I'm trying to save DataFrame with date type column to a parquet format to be used later in Athena. As far as I understand parquet has native DATE type, by the only type I can really use is datetime64[ns] with pyarrow engine (here is the same issue  discussed https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20089). The issue is I'd like to have date type rather than datetime in Athena schema. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change the column type of dataframe first and then dump it to parquet

Comment: If I keep the type as date, parquet schema saves it as null

Comment: In my project i have kept it as string in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Comment: I know I can do that, but It would be nice to avoid type casting down the line

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of Arrow.  Looking at the [Arrow's Pandas integration documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html) it seems like datetime.date can now be round-tripped.  And it [appears](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/src/parquet/arrow/schema.cc#L268) there is support for storing date columns in parquet.

Comment: You are right, @MicahKornfield. Thanks for point this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment I believe Apache Arrow 0.15.1 now supports round-tripping dates between Pandas and Parquet.